# Extend a joomla module

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am new to joomla and been trying to fully understand its workings,

There is a Joomla module called Latest News, I want to alter the output of the this module to include images drawn from the articles, i dont want to alter the tmpl/default.php file since I still want to maintain the usual look in other positions, I am guessing then that I have to use a plugin,

How then do I attach the plugin to the module if this is indeed the best way to extend the module in this instance?

Answer (score 0):

I'm a bit confused about what you want ... are you saying you sometimes want to include the images and sometimes not?

If you always want to include the images then you can do a regular template override for fault default.php. Don't alter the core file, put the file in your template folder under modules/mod_latest.  If you just want to use it in some instances put the modified file there but with a different name an then edit your module instance to use that layout by selecting that layout as an alternative layout. It's in the Advance Optons tab of J3 and one  of the sliders in J2.5

Comment: I want to use it in just some instances, I am trying out your approach, I created another layout file, i do not however find the new layout listed in the layout select box.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a plugin but a new module layout.

There are two places you can put your new module layout:

1. under /modules/your_module/tmpl/newlayout.php
2. under /templates/your_template/html/your_module/newlayout.php (but in this case, **make sure you also copy the default.php** - this is mandatory or the override won't be seen)

Now head to your module configuration and you will find your layout.